# Woocommerce: Do not empty cart after order placement with specific payment method

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to avoid woocommerce empty the cart if the user places an order with a specific payment method. In this case, if the payment method is BACS I don't want to empty the cart of the user after he places the order. is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to filter the default BACS payment gateway and make it not clear the cart when processing the payment. You will have to create your own custom BACS payment gateway and omit the `WC()->cart->empty_cart();` part.

Simple tutorial: https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-create-a-simple-woocommerce-payment-gateway/